# Unable to find PHP Syntax error

Tags: php, sql-server, syntax

I have a PHP MSSQL Query that worked previously, Hoever since I have changed an element that appears to have nothing to do with the query, it has started throwing errors.

Here is the query:

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['paper'])) {

$PageHTML = $_POST['ckeditor'];
$PageID = $_GET['id'];

$myServer = "**.***.***.**";
$myUser = "username";
$myPass = "password";
$myDB = "database";

$dbhandle = mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass)
or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer"); 
mssql_select_db($myDB) or die;

$dbTABLE = "Table_Name";
$query_sql = sprintf("UPDATE %s SET PageHTML = ('%s') WHERE PageID = '%d'",
$dbTABLE,
$PageHTML,
$PageID); 

if ($result = mssql_query($query_sql, $dbhandle)) {
header('Location: Manage.php');
}
}
?>
```

The errors is has started throwing are as follows:

```
Warning: mssql_query() [function.mssql-query]: message: Incorrect syntax near 're'.   (severity 15) in (file path) on line 59

Warning: mssql_query() [function.mssql-query]: message: Unclosed quotation mark after  the character string '</p> </div> </td> </tr> </tbody> </table>') WHERE PageID = '2''.   (severity 15) in (file path) on line 59
```

line 59 is this line:

```
if ($result = mssql_query($query_sql, $dbhandle)) {
```

I have checked it and am using similar syntax in other areas. Can anyone see where it is wrong?

Comment: Looks like `$query_sql` has a syntax error. Can you echo it?

Comment: yes, it seems to echo correctly. It echos: UPDATE Database_Table SET PageHTML = ('content of textarea') WHERE PageID = '1'

Comment: It looks like your error **is** `content of textarea` :p You should escape `$PageHTML`, it's opened to errors and injections.

Comment: This kind of database transaction will be source of errors, and as demonstrated by this error, subject to SQL injection. Have a look at http://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to add HTML code into database and there are troubles with quotes and special symbols. Yes, u can say you're doing `sprintf()`, but that function dont solve `sql` syntax problems. Try for example `addslashes(`) or else sanitizing php functions.

Comment: I am not in control of the front end code that pulls the data through and displays it, so I cannot implement addslashes because when its pulled through, I have no way of removing the slashes...

Comment: So u want to insert incorrect `sql` syntax data?  
Anyway Problem found - incorrect sql query syntax. There are two ways to solve it:  
1. Use addslashes (or else) sanitizing functions.  
2. Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php)